# Why I'm getting Method CacheXXXX is exposed as WebMethod, but thereis no corresponding wsdl operation If the wsdl hasn't changed?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, cxf, jax-ws

I hope you are doing very well,

I'm consuming a jax-ws and I generated the client with cxf 3.1.6 and SOAP UI but I'm having this error when I call a method, I've looked everywhere and the problem seems like the wsdl has changed but that is not my problem I've generated the client thousand times. Btw the method I'm calling is not the method I'm getting the error.

Server: Liberty Profile 8

This is the error trace

```
[ERROR   ] Error occurred during error handling, give up!
Method CacheXXXX is exposed as WebMethod, but there is no corresponding wsdl operation with name {[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/}CacheXXXX in the wsdl:portType{[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/}GeographicalDesignStructure
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Excepción lanzada por la clase de aplicación 'org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage:116'
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Method CacheXXXX is exposed as WebMethod, but there is no corresponding wsdl operation with name {[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/}CacheXXXX in the wsdl:portType{[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/}GeographicalDesignStructure
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Method CacheXXXX is exposed as WebMethod, but there is no corresponding wsdl operation with name {[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/}CacheXXXX in the wsdl:portType{[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/}GeographicalDesignStructure
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:163)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Method CacheXXXX is exposed as WebMethod, but there is no corresponding wsdl operation with name {[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/}CacheXXXX in the wsdl:portType{[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/}GeographicalDesignStructure
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.JavaMethodImpl.freeze(JavaMethodImpl.java:367)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.freeze(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:320)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:85)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:59)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:43)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.buildRuntimeModel(WSServiceDelegate.java:875)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createSEIPortInfo(WSServiceDelegate.java:892)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.addSEI(WSServiceDelegate.java:855)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:435)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:404)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:386)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:119)
    at com.company.geo.GeographicalDesignStructure.wsdl._1_0._mm.GeographicalDesignStructureService.getGeographicalDesignStructurePort(GeographicalDesignStructureService.java:72)
    at co.com.company.proyecto.integracion.GeographicalDesignStructureWS_BusConsumer.createSoapEndpoint(GeographicalDesignStructureWS_BusConsumer.java:54)
    at co.com.company.proyecto.integracion.GeographicalDesignStructureWS_BusConsumer.<init>(GeographicalDesignStructureWS_BusConsumer.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:119)
    at [internal classes]
    at co.com.company.proyecto.rest.resources.PaisesResource$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getPaises(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.performInvocation(LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.java:636)
    ... 1 more

[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: Se ha producido una excepción: java.lang.Throwable: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Method CacheXXXX is exposed as WebMethod, but there is no corresponding wsdl operation with name {[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/}CacheXXXX in the wsdl:portType{[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/}GeographicalDesignStructure
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4937)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Method CacheXXXX is exposed as WebMethod, but there is no corresponding wsdl operation with name {[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/}CacheXXXX in the wsdl:portType{[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/}GeographicalDesignStructure
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Method CacheXXXX is exposed as WebMethod, but there is no corresponding wsdl operation with name {[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/}CacheXXXX in the wsdl:portType{[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/}GeographicalDesignStructure
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:163)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Method CacheXXXX is exposed as WebMethod, but there is no corresponding wsdl operation with name {[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/}CacheXXXX in the wsdl:portType{[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/}GeographicalDesignStructure
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.JavaMethodImpl.freeze(JavaMethodImpl.java:367)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.freeze(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:320)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:85)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:59)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:43)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.buildRuntimeModel(WSServiceDelegate.java:875)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createSEIPortInfo(WSServiceDelegate.java:892)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.addSEI(WSServiceDelegate.java:855)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:435)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:404)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:386)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:119)
    at com.company.geo.GeographicalDesignStructure.wsdl._1_0._mm.GeographicalDesignStructureService.getGeographicalDesignStructurePort(GeographicalDesignStructureService.java:72)
    at co.com.company.proyecto.integracion.GeographicalDesignStructureWS_BusConsumer.createSoapEndpoint(GeographicalDesignStructureWS_BusConsumer.java:54)
    at co.com.company.proyecto.integracion.GeographicalDesignStructureWS_BusConsumer.<init>(GeographicalDesignStructureWS_BusConsumer.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:119)
    at [internal classes]
    at co.com.company.proyecto.rest.resources.PaisesResource$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getPaises(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.performInvocation(LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.java:636)
    ... 1 more
```

These are the wsdls

The first one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--File RemoteFiles/GeographicalDesignStructure_MM_wsGeographicalDesignStructure.wsdl, static library AFPServiciosExportComun_LIB--><wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="wsGeographicalDesignStructure_GeographicalDesignStructureHttp_Service" targetNamespace="http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:this="http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/">
  <wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:appinfo source="WMQI_APPINFO">
      <MRWSDLAppInfo imported="true">
        <binding hasEncoding="false" imported="true" name="wsGeographicalDesignStructure_GeographicalDesignStructureHttpBinding" originalBindingStyle="document"/>
      </MRWSDLAppInfo>
    </wsdl:appinfo>
  </wsdl:documentation>
  <wsdl:import location="https://direction:32342/GeographicalDesignStructure_MMWeb/sca/wsGeographicalDesignStructure?wsdl=wsdl0" namespace="http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/">
    </wsdl:import>
  <wsdl:binding name="wsGeographicalDesignStructure_GeographicalDesignStructureHttpBinding" type="this:GeographicalDesignStructure">
    <soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="paisConsulta">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/GeographicalDesignStructure/paisConsulta"/>
      <wsdl:input name="paisConsultaRequest"> 
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="paisConsultaResponse">
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="regionConsulta">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/GeographicalDesignStructure/regionConsulta"/>
      <wsdl:input name="regionConsultaRequest">
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="regionConsultaResponse">
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="zonaGeograficaConsulta">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/GeographicalDesignStructure/zonaGeograficaConsulta"/>
      <wsdl:input name="zonaGeograficaConsultaRequest">
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="zonaGeograficaConsultaResponse">
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="listaPaisConsulta"> 
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/GeographicalDesignStructure/listaPaisConsulta"/>
      <wsdl:input name="listaPaisConsultaRequest">
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="listaPaisConsultaResponse">
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="listaRegionConsulta">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/GeographicalDesignStructure/listaRegionConsulta"/>
      <wsdl:input name="listaRegionConsultaRequest">
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="listaRegionConsultaResponse">
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="listaZonaGeograficaConsulta">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/GeographicalDesignStructure/listaZonaGeograficaConsulta"/>
      <wsdl:input name="listaZonaGeograficaConsultaRequest">
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="listaZonaGeograficaConsultaResponse">
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="GeographicalDesignStructureService">
    <wsdl:port binding="this:wsGeographicalDesignStructure_GeographicalDesignStructureHttpBinding" name="GeographicalDesignStructurePort">
      <soap12:address location="https://direction:32342/GeographicalDesignStructure_MMWeb/sca/wsGeographicalDesignStructure"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The second one (Location: [This is not a link]https://direction:32342/GeographicalDesignStructure_MMWeb/sca/wsGeographicalDesignStructure?wsdl=wsdl0)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--File RemoteFiles/GeographicalDesignStructure.wsdl, static library AFPServiciosExportComun_LIB--><wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="GeographicalDesignStructure" targetNamespace="[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/" xmlns:bons1="[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/paisConsulta/schema/1.0/" xmlns:bons2="[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/regionConsulta/schema/1.0/" xmlns:tns="[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:appinfo source="WMQI_APPINFO">
            <MRWSDLAppInfo imported="true">
                <generatedXSD location="GeographicalDesignStructure_InlineSchema1.xsd"/>
            </MRWSDLAppInfo>
        </wsdl:appinfo>
    </wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:types>

        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/" xmlns:bons0="http://company.com/ZonaGeograficaConsultaSalida/schema/V1/" xmlns:bons4="[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/ZonaGeograficaConsultaEntrada/schema/1/" xmlns:ibmSchExtn="http://www.ibm.com/schema/extensions">
            <xsd:import namespace="[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/ZonaGeograficaConsultaEntrada/schema/1/" schemaLocation="https://vaxtpmde71:444/GeographicalDesignStructure_MMWeb/sca/wsGeographicalDesignStructure?xsd=xsd0"/>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://company.com/ZonaGeograficaConsultaSalida/schema/V1/" schemaLocation="https://vaxtpmde71:444/GeographicalDesignStructure_MMWeb/sca/wsGeographicalDesignStructure?xsd=xsd1"/>
            <xsd:import namespace="[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/regionConsulta/schema/1.0/" schemaLocation="https://vaxtpmde71:444/GeographicalDesignStructure_MMWeb/sca/wsGeographicalDesignStructure?xsd=xsd2"/>
            <xsd:import namespace="[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/regionConsulta/schema/1.0/" schemaLocation="https://vaxtpmde71:444/GeographicalDesignStructure_MMWeb/sca/wsGeographicalDesignStructure?xsd=xsd3"/>
            <xsd:import namespace="[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/paisConsulta/schema/1.0/" schemaLocation="https://vaxtpmde71:444/GeographicalDesignStructure_MMWeb/sca/wsGeographicalDesignStructure?xsd=xsd4"/>
            <xsd:import namespace="[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/paisConsulta/schema/1.0/" schemaLocation="https://vaxtpmde71:444/GeographicalDesignStructure_MMWeb/sca/wsGeographicalDesignStructure?xsd=xsd5"/>


            <xsd:import namespace="[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/ListaPaisConsulta/schema/1.0/" schemaLocation="https://vaxtpmde71:444/GeographicalDesignStructure_MMWeb/sca/wsGeographicalDesignStructure?xsd=xsd6"/>
            <xsd:import namespace="[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/ListaPaisConsulta/schema/1.0/" schemaLocation="https://vaxtpmde71:444/GeographicalDesignStructure_MMWeb/sca/wsGeographicalDesignStructure?xsd=xsd7"/>



            <xsd:import namespace="[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/ListaPaisConsulta/schema/1.0/" schemaLocation="https://vaxtpmde71:444/GeographicalDesignStructure_MMWeb/sca/wsGeographicalDesignStructure?xsd=xsd6"/>
    <xsd:import namespace="[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/ListaPaisConsulta/schema/1.0/" schemaLocation="https://vaxtpmde71:444/GeographicalDesignStructure_MMWeb/sca/wsGeographicalDesignStructure?xsd=xsd7"/>

        <xsd:import namespace="[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/ListaRegionConsulta/schema/1.0/" schemaLocation="https://vaxtpmde71:444/GeographicalDesignStructure_MMWeb/sca/wsGeographicalDesignStructure?xsd=xsd8"/>
    <xsd:import namespace="[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/ListaRegionConsulta/schema/1.0/" schemaLocation="https://vaxtpmde71:444/GeographicalDesignStructure_MMWeb/sca/wsGeographicalDesignStructure?xsd=xsd9"/>


        <xsd:import namespace="[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/ListaZonaGeograficaConsulta/schema/1.0/" schemaLocation="https://vaxtpmde71:444/GeographicalDesignStructure_MMWeb/sca/wsGeographicalDesignStructure?xsd=xsd10"/>
    <xsd:import namespace="[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/ListaZonaGeograficaConsulta/schema/1.0/" schemaLocation="https://vaxtpmde71:444/GeographicalDesignStructure_MMWeb/sca/wsGeographicalDesignStructure?xsd=xsd11"/>  
            <xsd:include schemaLocation="https://vaxtpmde71:444/GeographicalDesignStructure_MMWeb/sca/wsGeographicalDesignStructure?xsd=xsd12"/>

        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="paisConsultaResponseMsg">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:paisConsultaResponse" name="paisConsultaResult">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="regionConsultaRequestMsg">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:regionConsulta" name="regionConsultaParameters">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="regionConsultaResponseMsg">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:regionConsultaResponse" name="regionConsultaResult">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="zonaGeograficaConsultaRequestMsg">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:zonaGeograficaConsulta" name="zonaGeograficaConsultaParameters">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="paisConsultaRequestMsg">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:paisConsulta" name="paisConsultaParameters">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="zonaGeograficaConsultaResponseMsg">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:zonaGeograficaConsultaResponse" name="zonaGeograficaConsultaResult">
        </wsdl:part>


    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="CacheXXXXRequestMsg">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:CacheXXXX" name="CacheXXXXParameters"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="CacheXXXXResponseMsg">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:CacheXXXXResponse" name="CacheXXXXResult"/>
    </wsdl:message>


    <wsdl:message name="listaPaisConsultaRequestMsg">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:listaPaisConsulta" name="listaPaisConsultaParameters">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="listaPaisConsultaResponseMsg">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:listaPaisConsultaResponse" name="listaPaisConsultaResult">
        </wsdl:part>

    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="listaRegionConsultaRequestMsg">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:listaRegionConsulta" name="listaRegionConsultaParameters">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="listaRegionConsultaResponseMsg">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:listaRegionConsultaResponse" name="listaRegionConsultaResult">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:message name="listaZonaGeograficaConsultaRequestMsg">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:listaZonaGeograficaConsulta" name="listaZonaGeograficaConsultaParameters">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="listaZonaGeograficaConsultaResponseMsg">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:listaZonaGeograficaConsultaResponse" name="listaZonaGeograficaConsultaResult">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="GeographicalDesignStructure">
        <wsdl:operation name="paisConsulta">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:paisConsultaRequestMsg" name="paisConsultaRequest">
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:paisConsultaResponseMsg" name="paisConsultaResponse">
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="regionConsulta">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:regionConsultaRequestMsg" name="regionConsultaRequest">
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:regionConsultaResponseMsg" name="regionConsultaResponse">
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="zonaGeograficaConsulta">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:zonaGeograficaConsultaRequestMsg" name="zonaGeograficaConsultaRequest">
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:zonaGeograficaConsultaResponseMsg" name="zonaGeograficaConsultaResponse">
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="CacheXXXX">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:CacheXXXXRequestMsg" name="CacheXXXXRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:CacheXXXXResponseMsg" name="CacheXXXXResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="listaPaisConsulta">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:listaPaisConsultaRequestMsg" name="listaPaisConsultaRequest">
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:listaPaisConsultaResponseMsg" name="listaPaisConsultaResponse">
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="listaRegionConsulta">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:listaRegionConsultaRequestMsg" name="listaRegionConsultaRequest">
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:listaRegionConsultaResponseMsg" name="listaRegionConsultaResponse">
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="listaZonaGeograficaConsulta">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:listaZonaGeograficaConsultaRequestMsg" name="listaZonaGeograficaConsultaRequest">
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:listaZonaGeograficaConsultaResponseMsg" name="listaZonaGeograficaConsultaResponse">
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out, the problem was that the operation CacheXXXX wasn't on the binding tag and because of it cxf was promting the error

```
Method CacheXXXX is exposed as WebMethod, but there is no corresponding     wsdl operation with name {[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/}CacheXXXX in the wsdl:portType{[this is not a link]http://company.com/GeographicalDesignStructure/wsdl/1.0/_MM/}GeographicalDesignStructure
```

There are two options to solve the problem, delete the operation (That was the one I took) or put CacheXXXX into the binding tag.

I hope this helps somebody